# How to import mysqldump in Node.js application?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

Only solution I found was [node-mysql-importer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mysql-importer), it does nothing as intended. In the console, it shows

```
importSQL done: ./lib/api/sqldumps/footballers2655c10.sql
DONE!
SQL dump successfully loaded
```

But nothing is present in the database!

Here is my code:

```
import http from 'http'
import app from './app'
import importer from 'node-mysql-importer'

import db from './api/models'
import config from './api/config'

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

var mysql = require('mysql')

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  'host': config.db.host,
  'user': config.db.user,
  'password': config.db.password
})

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err
  con.query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS footballers", function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err
    sqldumpImporter ()
  })
})

const server = http.createServer(app)

function sqldumpImporter () {
  importer.config({
    'host': config.db.host,
    'user': config.db.user,
    'password': config.db.password,
    'database': config.db.database
  })

  importer.importSQL('./lib/api/sqldumps/footballers2655c10.sql').then( () => {
    console.log('SQL dump successfully loaded')
    syncSequelize()
  }).catch( err => {
    console.log(`error: ${err}`)
  })
}

function syncSequelize() {
  db.sequelize.sync()
    .then(() => {
      server.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on port ${port}`))
    })
}
```

There are no errors initially, but then because of table does not exists, programs stops execution.

```
ERROR: Error: ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: Table 'footballers.footballers' doesn't exist
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

The database is still empty after execution. Here is the sql file I'm trying to load : https://github.com/danivijay/footballers-app/blob/master/server/lib/api/sqldumps/footballers2655c10.sql

And here is my codebase : https://github.com/danivijay/footballers-app/tree/master/server

What went wrong in my code? Is there any better solution to import mysqldump(.sql) files with NodeJS?

Comment: Check your sqldump: are you sure it uses the db you think it uses?

Comment: Yeah, here is my config file from which the database name loads : https://github.com/danivijay/footballers-app/blob/master/server/lib/api/config/index.js

Uses the database `footballers`, and it is present in the host. @Mihai

Comment: As a long-time DBA, I can't really think of any compelling reason for restoring a dump file from within Node (or any other language, for that matter), when there is an established, standard tool for such a task.  Why would you not restore the dump file using the standard `mysql` utility?

Comment: I built this project for a hackathon. We've provided the sql dump file. I had to make it up and running with one command.@Michael-sqlbot